# What Stack Exchange site is suitable for home security cameras?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I recently purchased a [Lorex](https://www.lorextechnology.com/) security camera system for my house, much like [this one](http://m.costco.com/Lorex-8-Channel-IP-NVR-with-2TB-HDD,-8-1080p-Cameras-with-130'-Night-Vision.product.100217003.html). I have some questions about it. Should I ask on Super User?

> I'm not drilling holes, but I want to expand this system with more cameras using a PoE switch. The system already comes with eight cameras and is an eight-channel system. I want to add four more cameras using PoE. The manual sort of says you can. Lorex says you can't. A buddy of mine who works in this industry says you can. I don't know who to believe.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the nature of the questions? E.g., drilling holes in the walls to run cable might go to [DIY.SE]; configuration of the connections might go to [SU]; keeping the cameras clean might go to [Lifehacks.SE].

Comment: Hi josh, more technical.  Not drilling holes but if I can expand this system with more cameras using a poe switch.  The system already comes with 8 cams and is an 8 channel system.  I want to add 4 more cameras using a poe.  The manual sort of says you can.  Lorex says you can't.  A buddy of mine who works in this industry says you can.  I don't know who to believe.

Comment: @Josh Caswell so where would I post this?

Comment: You should use the [edit] button to add the info you posted into your question rather than leaving it as a comment.

Comment: You ask if you should ask on Superuser.  Have you read the help page and tour page on Superuser?  What are your thoughts?  And why would you think it would be on-topic there?  They have an explicit list of topics that are on-topic there, listed on their help pages; I'm not seeing why you think that security cameras fit any of those.

Comment: @Catija - I did apparently there doesnt exist a SE site to help with this?

Comment: Additionally, if you have questions about the config, or most appropriate location to ensure coverage, etc - they could fit on Security Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

> The manual sort of says you can. Lorex says you can't. A buddy of mine who works in this industry says you can. I don't know who to believe.

If the question is "who can I believe", it is most likely primarily opinion based... No, just joking. I think this is a very hard question to answer. The question is more a hardware recommendation question (what device should I use? is X compatible with Y?). I don't see a community that fits a question like this.

The best fit is [Home Improvements](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), which has a tag for [security](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) and [wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiring). That might come as close as it gets.

Some other sites might be border-line okay (check their help, and possibly ask on their meta).